# How do you put dynamic content in an action mailer subject line?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I'm trying to put the name of my app in the subject line of emails that action mailer sends. I have no problem doing this with the default from email address, but when I try to add it to the subject it sends it through as plain text `<%= app_name %>`.

Here's my mailers/user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base  
  add_template_helper(ApplicationHelper)
  extend ApplicationHelper

  default from: "#{app_name} <#{system_email}>"

  def reset_password_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = "#{root_url}/password_resets/#{user.reset_password_token}/edit"
    mail(:to => user.email,
         :subject => "Reset Your Password | #{app_name}")
  end
end
```

And here's what I have in my application helper:

```
  def app_name
    'Tip Share'
  end

  def app_domain
    'tipshare.herokuapp.com'
  end

  def system_email
    'info@wingardcreative.com'
  end
```

Neither `#{app_name}` or `<%= app_name %>` works. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding it like this:

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

Answer (score 0):

By extending `UserMailer` with `ApplicationHelper`, those methods are available as class methods - which is why the reference in `default from: "#{app_name} <#{system_email}>"` works.
Within the `reset_password_email` method, `app_name` would be an undefined local variable.
So you either need to additionally `include ApplicationHelper`, or call it with `self.class.app_name`.

Comment: Hmm, I tried putting `"include ApplicationHelper"` inside the `reset_password_email` method and that triggered an error. I tried `extend ApplicationHelper` instead and that worked but still delivered `<%= app_name %>` as plain text. If I use `#{app_name}` there are no errors but the email doesn't get delivered. If I use `<%= self.class.app_name %>` the email doesn't get delivered.

Comment: The `include` statement is a class level directive, like the `extend` you have in your example code. These don't go within the methods. `extend` adds the methods from the named module as class methods, while `include` adds them as instance methods.
In your current `reset_password_email` method, you need to stick with the interpolation `#{ app_name }`. Since you've already extended your helper methods, I would just use `#{ self.class.app_name }` here, in which case you don't need the `include`. It's one or the other, both aren't needed.